# operating over strings, python

Tags: python, split, tokenize

How to define a function that takes a string (sentence) and inserts an extra space after a period if the period is directly followed by a letter.

```
sent = "This is a test.Start testing!"
def normal(sent):
    list_of_words = sent.split()
    ...
```

This should print out

> "This is a test. Start testing!"

I suppose I should use `split()` to brake a string into a list, but what next?

**P.S.** The solution has to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner non-regex answer:

```
def normal(sent):
    return ".".join(" " + s if i > 0 and s[0].isalpha() else s for i, s in enumerate(sent.split(".")))
```

Here is a multi-line version using a similar approach. You may find it more readable.

```
def normal(sent):
    sent = sent.split(".")
    result = sent[:1]
    for item in sent[1:]:
        if item[0].isalpha():
            item = " " + item
        result.append(item)
    return ".".join(result)
```

Using a regex is probably the better way, though.

Comment: Very clever.  I love that it avoids regular expressions.  I don't, however, like it's level of complexity.  I wish I could give a 1/2 vote.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be much more readable as a traditional for loop. :-) In fact I will just go ahead and add such a version in an edit.

Comment: Wow, can't believe you came back to a question 5 days later! Upvote for you.

Answer (score 8):

Use `re.sub`.  Your regular expression will match a period (`\.`) followed by a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`).  Your replacement string will contain a reference to the second group (\2), which was the letter matched in the regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\.([a-zA-Z])', r'. \1', 'This is a test.This is a test. 4.5 balloons.')
'This is a test. This is a test. 4.5 balloons'
```

Note the choice of `[a-zA-Z]` for the regular expression.  This matches just letters.  We do not use `\w` because it would insert spaces into a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force without any checks:

```
>>> sent = "This is a test.Start testing!"
>>> k = sent.split('.')
>>> ". ".join(l)
'This is a test. Start testing!'
>>>
```

For removing spaces:

```
>>> sent = "This is a test. Start testing!"
>>> k = sent.split('.')
>>> l = [x.lstrip(' ') for x in k]
>>> ". ".join(l)
'This is a test. Start testing!'
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the requirement that the period be followed by a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Another regex-based solution, might be a tiny bit faster than Steven's (only one pattern match, and a blacklist instead of a whitelist):

```
import re
re.sub(r'\.([^\s])', r'. \1', some_string)
```

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't need to make two groups, just one.  But [^\s] would split on more than letters.  Most importantly, decimal numbers would have spaces inserted, so I would stick with [a-zA-Z].

Answer (score 0):

Improving pyfunc's answer:

> > > sent="This is a test.Start testing!"
> > >
> > > k=sent.split('.')
> > >
> > > k='. '.join(k)
> > >
> > > k.replace('.  ','. ')

'This is a test. Start testing!'